React Native InjectJavaScript not working
I’m currently using the following:
"react": "18.3.1",
"react-native": "0.76.1",
"react-native-permissions": "^5.2.0",
"react-native-webview": "^13.12.2"

However, the injected JavaScript code that works perfectly on Android does not function on iOS.
render() {
        let yourAlert = 'alert("hello")'
        return (
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <WebView
                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                domStorageEnabled={true}
                injectedJavaScript={yourAlert}
                source={{uri:"https://www.google.com"}} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                onMessage={(event) => {
                    console.log('event: ', event)
                }}
              />;
          </View>
        );
    }

What can I try next?

this might not work on just any website like google.com try using custom html or write a function in you custom html and call it using injectedJavaScript. and the onMessage callback function will not work unless you add this in the webview
injectedJavaScript={`
        window.ReactNativeWebView = window.ReactNativeWebView || {};
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage = window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage || function(data) {
          window.postMessage(data, '*');
        };
        true; // note: this is required, or you'll sometimes get silent failures
      `}

and send a message from the website code like this
window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(
                        JSON.stringify({
                            data: data
                        })
                    );

hope it helps
